# how to read local external json file for drawing graph with cytoscape.js

Tags: json, graph, localhost, cytoscape

i have a web application using cytoscape.js to drawing web base graph.
i want to load json data and style from files on local Machine.
the url on the internet work but localhost url and local file path dosn't work
what can i do